# CSS breadcrumb arrow pointing left

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I found this css breadcrumb pointing right and I want to point to the left. Believe me that I tried over and over without any success. Please someone show me how to do it.

```css
div span {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:-1px;
    
  }
  
  div span:after, div span:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index:2;
  }

  div span:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-left-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  div span:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-left-color: #FFF;
    border-width: 22px;
    margin-top: -22px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Home</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invert the `border-left` , and `margin` , `position` properties to achieve this. Here goes the code sample.

```css
div span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #88b7d5;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
div span:after,
div span:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
div span:after {
 
  
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-right-color: #88b7d5;
  border-width: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
div span:before {
 
  border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-right-color: #FFF;
  border-width: 22px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:30px;">
  <span>Home</span>
  <span>Home</span>
</div>
```